# Does scrapy LinkExtractor check for links in every yield(ed) Request?

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy has the `LinkExtractor` class which follows links and returns callbacks

Does the `Linkextractor` check for links in the response from every single `yield`(ed) `Request`?

including links found in pages which were `yield`(ed) by other rules?

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy's LinkExtractor, by itself, doesn't follow links.  It does exactly as its name implies, Extracts links from a response object.  That's it.

If you take a look at the `CrawlSpider` example in the [official Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example), LinkExtractor is just responsible for extracting all of the links (returning them as `scrapy.link.Link` objects).  The "Rule" object is responsible for taking each of these links and doing something with it.

You can test this out for yourself.  Load up the Scrapy shell and do the following on one of your responses:

```
>>> from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
>>> LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
[Link(url='https://imade.this.up/', text='Dont Click This', fragment='', nofollow=False), 
Link(url='https://this.too/', text='Not Real', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

As far as `rules` go, if we're still talking about CrawlSpider, then yes each `Rule` is applied to every response.  Look at `scrapy.spiders.crawl.CrawlSpider` to see the details of how it's handling Rules.

P.S. Of course, your spider can be different! Just creating a `Rule` object isn't going to make your custom `Spider` follow all links in every response!